# How to solve the large-scale Jar transitive dependency hell problem in Java language?

Tags: java, jar

I'm grappling with a transitive dependency issue within a large organization, boasting over 2,300 R&D personnel and more than 4,000 internal JARs.

The predicament I'm facing is that whenever I incorporate any JAR and aim to access the service behind it via RPC, this JAR package introduces 1.5GB of transitive dependencies. We have thousands of such JARs within the company.

The question is, how do we synchronize these JAR package versions internally? All Java projects are mandated to use Maven and inherit a unified pom.xml. This pom.xml delineates the latest version of 4,000 JARs, ensuring each project utilizes the most recent version to circumvent class conflicts.

On the server side, a server-side project constructs a deployment product exceeding 2GB, with over 400,000 Java classes under the classpath. Approximately 70% of the volume is contributed by classes compiled and generated by proto. When I initiate Spring Boot, Spring scans the complete classpath. The service startup is considerably slow, and the JVM metaspace surpasses 1GB.

The anti-corrosion design leaves much to be desired. The request and response in the SDK will nest the protobuf classes of other JAR packages. Then, this protobuf class may nest protobuf classes in other JAR packages. Most of these 4,000 JAR packages follow this pattern, forming a complex graph.

This is a convoluted situation that I need to resolve. Does anyone have any viable solutions to help me tackle this JAR hell problem and protobuf issue?